# Find most frequent record in WHOLE table

Tags: sql, ms-access

In Microsoft Access 2010 I have a table that looks like this (of course it's much bigger):

```
Date           A         B         C         D         E           F
2008-01-02    25        24        27        25        65          34
2008-01-03    28        25        38        10        43          25
2008-01-04    14        16        25         9        22          55
2008-01-05    25        16        11        25        99          44
2008-01-06    21        16        11        25        25          98
```

And I have to find the value that occurs most frequently in all columns (one number) and tell the number of its occurs ('Date' is not important).

So in this example it would be 25, which occurs 9 times.

Could you help me, because I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: You're looking for the most frequent number across all the columns?  P.S. MS Access and MySQL are 2 different things and they use a slightly different SQL syntax.

Comment: 1. See normalization. A normalized design might look like this... date, type (e.g. A, B, etc), val

Comment: How big can the numbers get? I don't think you can do this in a query, but I have a solution in VBA

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, I am looking exactly for something like this.

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you... but I totally don't know how to do it. The problem is that I have to do it somehow in C++ or Microsoft Access/Excel (it's my choice) and I have to do it fast. During exam I can get something like this: http://speedyshare.com/8j9ZJ/historia.txt (this is the example file that I am working on right now) and I get couple of tasks to do. Most of them are quite easy, like to count average etc., but I just can't get through this one.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn - numbers are quite small (as you can see in this .txt file)

Comment: In that case use UNION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT val, COUNT(*) ttl FROM
(
SELECT date, 'A' type, a val FROM my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT date, 'B', b val FROM my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT date, 'C', c val FROM my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT date, 'D', d val FROM my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT date, 'E', e val FROM my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT date, 'F', f val FROM my_table
) x
GROUP BY val ORDER BY ttl DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This is a generic solution, so some parts of it are actually superfluous to this specific problem.

Oh, this solution for MySQL, but I imagine you can adapt it.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! Admittedly, I made quite different query but it is based on your idea. Firstly, I made one query using UNION to list all my numbers in one column and then another one to find the most frequent number in this column, which wasn't a big deal.

Comment: Glad somebody's paying attention!